# Use both builtin speaker and headphones on Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: lenovo-laptop, microsoft-teams

I am having a Lenovo Thinkpad which comes with a headset plug. When I plugin my headset, the builtin sound will become silent and I hear sound in the headset.

Now, is it possible to split the output into two separate "soundcards" so I can let Microsoft Teams ring using the builtin speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headset jack on a computer is a mechanical switch. When the plug is inserted, a metal contact moves away, opening the circuit between the sound source and the speaker. The pin plug then "collects" that signal to the headphones. It's not particularly practical to consider that you can bridge the connection, as you'd have to open the laptop to short the two locations.

One can purchase a USB audio adapter to provide a non-mechanical sound source for your headphones, leaving the on-board speaker for other purposes. Various sources including Amazon appear when using USB headphone jack as the search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Lenovo laptop, but on my Lenovo PC, there's a program called Realtek Audio Console, open it and go to "Device advanced settings" and make sure that the selected radiobutton under Playback Device is "Make internal and external output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously."

Hope this helps.